# Specifying base listener/visitor implementation with antlr

Tags: java, antlr, dsl, antlr4

I know you can define members for the antlr4 parser with the `@members` section. Is there something similar for defining default implementation of the BaseListener/BaseVisitor generated classes? The default implementations do - for visitor call visistChildren(), for listener do nothing.

The reason I am asking is because I am currently implementing both listener and visitor versions of the interface so I can compare performance and they both forward the call to a helper class that does the actual work in a very boilerplate way:

```
@Override
public Boolean visitExpression1(@NotNull FilterParser.Expression1Context ctx) {
    return evaluationHandler.eval(ctx);
}

@Override
public Boolean visitExpression2(@NotNull FilterParser.Expression2Context ctx) {
    return evaluationHandler.eval(ctx);
}
...
```

It would be nice if i can specify this in the grammar file somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: Well that extra data/functionality has nothing to do with the grammar, so I suggest that you leave it outside and do normal Java sharing of information.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that inherits the `BaseListener`, call it `MyBaseListener`, add your stuff there and inherit this new class.